# Does a Magic Trackpad have a button?

Tags: magic-trackpad

Does a Magic Trackpad have a button, as opposed to just being a trackpad? I am not sure if this even makes sense, so let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: No need to clarify, that aspect of the trackpad is decidedly non-obvious until you start deliberately poking around to see what's going on.

Comment: @Cajun I was't sure if my question was clear.

Comment: This is certainly hidden magic, and I would bet heavily patented; when you see how this "simple device" was engineered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it has two physical buttons on the edge lacking the battery tray. The two rubber feet on the bottom-front of the trackpad press against  internal switches.

For these to activate, you have to use it on a hard surface. The software tap-to-click that senses your finger pad deforming as it taps the immovable glass surface also will trigger a tap independently from the physical buttons.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a "button" in the traditional sense, but clicking is supported in two ways:

1. Pressing down anywhere on the trackpad engages a click mechanism in the base.
2. Lightly tapping on the trackpad registers a click.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  But sort of hidden.  If you reach under the trackpad, the feet on the bottom front act as a single button when pressed.

If you justs press the entire trackpad down on a hard surface to activate these buttons on the bottom.  But, if you are holding the trackpad in the air, squeezing one of the bottom feet directly will also work.